DDL Replication Issue with SymmetricDS: New fields do not replicate inserted data
I'm using SymmetricDS to replicate a table structure (DDL), and I ran the following sequence of commands to sync the triggers and send the table schema:
bin\symadmin.bat -e rada-000 --node=001 sync-triggers
bin\symadmin.bat -e rada-000 --node=001 send-schema TABLE
After replicating the DDL, the new field in the table appears correctly in the target database. However, when I insert data into this table, the content of the new field is not being replicated to the target node. The other data in the table is replicated without issues.
I have verified that:

The table structure is synchronized between the two nodes.
The triggers seem to be working fine for the old columns.

Question:
What might be preventing the replication of the data in the new field? Is there any additional procedure I should follow after DDL replication to ensure that the data in the new fields is properly replicated?
Environment:

SymmetricDS version: 3.15.7
Operating system: root node: Windows 10, node: Ubuntu 22.04
Database: Firebird 3.10


have you checked the sym_table entries for the table after the column has been added and rows are inserted with values in the new column?

Thank you for your comment!
In my case, SymmetricDS did not create the sym_table in my database. Instead, there are the sym_table_reload_request and sym_table_reload_status tables.
I checked the SymmetricDS trigger on the  table where I added the new column TEST, and I noticed that, even after executing the command bin\symadmin.bat -e rada-000 --node=001 sync-triggers, the insert trigger did not include the new column in the insertion.

It seems that the trigger was not updated to include the new column TEST, which might be preventing the correct replication of data. If you have any suggestions on how I can resolve this, I would appreciate it!

Here is the command you should run on node 000: bin\symadmin.bat -e rada-000 sync-triggers
If this is not detecting the change in the table you can use :bin\symadmin.bat -e rada-000 sync-triggers -f to force it to rebuild the trigger.
It should automatically sync triggers on the target node when it detects a schema change is loaded. There was a bug related to this issue that was fixed in 3.15.8 https://issues.symmetricds.org/view.php?id=6526

It worked! Thank you very much for your help!
